# Subobjects in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Why in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces the subspaces of a given object coincide with its subobjects?
This is not the case in the category of topological spaces.

Comment: what is your definition of "subobject" in a category?Related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject)?

Comment: Yes. Equivalence classes of monomorphisms having the given object as codomain.

Comment: The category of compact Hausdorff spaces is almost “algebraic”, it has exponential objects too e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm not sure there's anything "almost" about it! Compact Hausdorff spaces are a perfectly good monadic category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous injection; then $f[X]$ is a compact subspace of $Y$ homeomorphic to $X$, and a monomorphism $g:Z\to Y$ is equivalent to $f:X\to Y$ iff $Z$ is homeomorphic to $X$ (and both are homeomorphic to $f[X]=g[Z]$). In short, the subobject is completely determined by a compact subspace of $Y$, and *vice versa*.

Comment: Did you use the Hausdorff assumption somewhere?

Comment: @Theo: Yes: without it there is no guarantee that $f$ is actually an embedding. The crucial fact is that if $\tau$ is a compact Hausdorff topology on some set, no finer topology is compact, and no coarser topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Theo: You’re welcome!